Loop space, parametrization equivalence and the issue of giving a topology
This question has been motivated by p.165 of this book.
As in the cited link above, we consider the following space of paraemtrized piecewise $C^1$ loops
\begin{equation}
X:= \Bigl\{ x : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n \, \mid \, x(0)=x(1), x\text{ is a piecewise } C^1 \text{ loop and the second derivative } x'' \text{ exists in the weak sense as an element of } L^2\bigl(S^1, \mathbb{R}^n \bigr) \Bigr\}
\end{equation}
A metric on $X$ is defined to be
\begin{equation}
d(x,y):= \lVert x-y \rVert_2 + \lVert x'-y'\rVert_2 + \lVert x''-y''\rVert_2
\end{equation}
Well, it seems to me that $(X,d)$ should just be modelled on the Sobolev space $H^2\bigl(S^1, \mathbb{R}^n \bigr)$.
Next, we let $x \simeq y$ for $x,y \in X$ if the corresponding graphs of the continuous versions are equal:
\begin{equation}
\{ x(s)\, \mid \, s \in S^1 \} = \{ y(s)\, \mid \, s \in S^1 \}
\end{equation}
$\simeq$ is clearly an equivalence relation.
Then, I have two questions.
First,

What exactly is the topology of the quotient space $X / \simeq$? p.165 of this book doesn't seem to provide enough details. For me, $X / \simeq$ does not look like a vector space. Is it at least a separable complete metric space under the general construction of a quotient metric space?

Second,

The purpose of introducing the relation $\simeq$ is that loop integrals should be invariant under $\simeq$. However, is this indeed the case? More specifically, if $x \simeq y$ as above, is it possible to find a re-parametrization between $x$ and $y$ to prove invariance of the loop integral by chain rule as in this proof?

I hope this question is nontrivial enough to be posted here...Could anyone please provide any insight?
